# Finding all possible paths in java recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

When I call the function which finds all the paths to reach the right bottom of the matrix using a recursive approach, it was updating the visited paths to -1 so that it will not loop, but in Java if we update the array in one direction it updates the value to -1 and other possibilities are taken able to taken.

So I need a solution for a Java program from updating the original array.

```
package other;

public class Reach_end {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] path = {
                {1, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1},
                {1, 1, 1, 1},
                {1, 0, 1, 1},
        };
        
        System.out.println(pathFinder(path, 0, 0));
    }

    private static int pathFinder(int[][] path, int row, int col) {
        path[row][col] = -1;
        int temp = 0;
        if (row == path.length-1 && col == path.length-1) {
            System.out.println("path found");
            return 1;
        }
        if (row+1 < path.length && path[row+1][col] == 1) {
            System.out.println("Moved down " + (row+1) +" " + col);
            temp = pathFinder(path, row+1, col);
            if (temp >= 1) {
                return temp+1;
            }
        }
        temp = 0;
        if (col+1 < path.length && path[row][col+1] == 1) {
            System.out.println("Moved right " + row + " " + (col+1));
            temp = pathFinder(path, row, col+1);
            if (temp >= 1) {
                return temp+1;
            }
        }
        temp = 0;
        if (row-1 >= 0 && path[row-1][col] == 1) {
            System.out.println("Moved up " + (row-1) + " " + col);
            temp = pathFinder(path, row-1, col);
            if (temp >= 1) {
                return temp+1;
            }
        }
        temp = 0;
        if (col-1 >= 0 && path[row][col-1] == 1) {
            System.out.println("Moved left" + (row) + " " + (col-1));
            temp = pathFinder(path, row, col-1);
            if (temp >= 1) {
                return temp+1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I need a solution preventing array from updating.

Answer (score 0):

You want the -1 to be there to not get into infinite loops while doing the recursion but be removed again at some point, so you can try other paths.

The usual way of doing that is save the value before overwriting it and then put it back before returning.

```
private static int pathFinder(int[][] path, int row, int col) {
    int saved = path[row][col];
    path[row][col] = -1;
    // ...
    if (row+1 < path.length && path[row+1][col] == 1) {
        System.out.println("Moved down " + (row+1) +" " + col);
        temp = pathFinder(path, row+1, col);
        if (temp >= 1) {
            path[row][col] = saved;
            return temp+1;
        }
    }
    // etc, make sure to cover all the returns
```